# Find out which is a regular language

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory, dfa, tableofcontents

[image: Regular language]

My Argument/Answer is if y is aregular set then there exits a DFA which accepts y. In the L1 there is a condition that y=x^n, that x will belong to L1,as y is accepted by DFA. So is x^n and so is x so L1 is regular. Now L2 --> here the condition is x=y^n. Here y is accepted by DFA so is y^n so which is equal to x so x can be accepted by DFA. This makes both L1,L2 regular

Is my argument right?

Comment: There's something wrong with your answer because `y` is not a set.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. If there is a DFA that accepts x^n, that doesn't mean it also has to accept x.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems like it's poorly-posed. For example, if we take A = {a}, then L1 is the language {a} and L2 is the language a*, both of which are regular. If we pick A = a*b, then L1 = a *b (which is regular) and L2 = { (a<sup>n</sup>b)<sup>m</sup> | m, n ≥ 0 }, which is not regular (using the pumping lemma). In other words, the answer depends on the choice of A.

Comment: If A = a* b then L2 = (a*b)* which is of course regular. See my answer for details.

Comment: @chazisop Are you sure about that? L_2, intuitively, is the language you get by picking individual strings in A and replicating them some number of times. As a result, you wouldn't have aabab in L_2 because there's no fixed string in A you could pick and replicate twice to get aabab.

Comment: Sorry, the comment above was not formatted properly. In the example L2 should be ( a * b ) * . n and y are not restricted to some specific selection, that is just set builder notation for specifying the conditions a specific x must satisfy. If you look at the definition it says the following: x is in L2 if there exists a string y in A and a non-negative integer n such that x=y^n. Therefore, for every string y in A and every non-negative integer n, y^n is in L2. But this is precisely A*.

Comment: @chazisop (a* b)* contains the string abaab, which is not in L2.